# What change between pandas 1.1.5 and 1.3.4 changed the set_index / reset_index process?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have some code that was working fine until someone on our team upgraded pandas from 1.1.5 to 1.3.4.  Here's a simplified version of the code that's causing the issue.  I would ideally like to know how to change the set_index and/or reset_index calls so that they will work under both 1.1.5 and 1.3.4.

pandas 1.1.5:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> from pandas import Timestamp
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'label': {1000: 'apple',
  1001: 'carrot',
  1002: 'carrot',
  1003: 'apple',
  1004: 'apple',
  1005: 'carrot'},
 'date': {1000: Timestamp('2021-10-27 00:00:00'),
  1001: Timestamp('2021-10-27 00:00:00'),
  1002: Timestamp('2021-10-28 00:00:00'),
  1003: Timestamp('2021-10-28 00:00:00'),
  1004: Timestamp('2021-10-29 00:00:00'),
  1005: Timestamp('2021-10-29 00:00:00')},
 'stock': {1000: 100,
  1001: 150,
  1002: 75,
  1003: 50,
  1004: 200,
  1005: 20}})
>>> df_rolling = df.set_index(['label', 'date']).groupby(level='label').rolling(window=7, min_periods=1).sum()
>>> df_rolling
        stock
label        
apple   100.0
apple   150.0
apple   350.0
carrot  150.0
carrot  225.0
carrot  245.0
>>> df_rolling.index
MultiIndex([( 'apple',),
            ( 'apple',),
            ( 'apple',),
            ('carrot',),
            ('carrot',),
            ('carrot',)],
           names=['label'])
>>> df_rolling = df_rolling.reset_index()
>>> df_rolling.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=6, step=1)
```

pandas 1.3.4:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> from pandas import Timestamp
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'label': {1000: 'apple',
  1001: 'carrot',
  1002: 'carrot',
  1003: 'apple',
  1004: 'apple',
  1005: 'carrot'},
 'date': {1000: Timestamp('2021-10-27 00:00:00'),
  1001: Timestamp('2021-10-27 00:00:00'),
  1002: Timestamp('2021-10-28 00:00:00'),
  1003: Timestamp('2021-10-28 00:00:00'),
  1004: Timestamp('2021-10-29 00:00:00'),
  1005: Timestamp('2021-10-29 00:00:00')},
 'stock': {1000: 100,
  1001: 150,
  1002: 75,
  1003: 50,
  1004: 200,
  1005: 20}})
>>> df_rolling = df.set_index(['label', 'date']).groupby(level='label').rolling(window=7, min_periods=1).sum()
>>> df_rolling                                                                                                                                                                                     
                          stock
label  label  date             
apple  apple  2021-10-27  100.0
              2021-10-28  150.0
              2021-10-29  350.0
carrot carrot 2021-10-27  150.0
              2021-10-28  225.0
              2021-10-29  245.0
>>> df_rolling.index                                                                                                                                                                               
MultiIndex([( 'apple',  'apple', '2021-10-27'),
            ( 'apple',  'apple', '2021-10-28'),
            ( 'apple',  'apple', '2021-10-29'),
            ('carrot', 'carrot', '2021-10-27'),
            ('carrot', 'carrot', '2021-10-28'),
            ('carrot', 'carrot', '2021-10-29')],
           names=['label', 'label', 'date'])
>>> df_rolling = df_rolling.reset_index()                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-8b81c1e32ea2> in <module>
----> 1 df_rolling = df_rolling.reset_index()

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in reset_index(self, level, drop, inplace, col_level, col_fill)
   5797                     )
   5798 
-> 5799                 new_obj.insert(0, name, level_values)
   5800 
   5801         new_obj.index = new_index

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates)
   4412         if not allow_duplicates and column in self.columns:
   4413             # Should this be a different kind of error??
-> 4414             raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {column}, already exists")
   4415         if not isinstance(loc, int):
   4416             raise TypeError("loc must be int")

ValueError: cannot insert label, already exists
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `set_index` part in `df.set_index(['label', 'date']).groupby(level='label').rolling(...)` ?  For each label, do you want compute the rolling sum with a time window of 7 days?

Comment: @HarryPlotter Yep, that's it.  (If you remove the `set_index` call, you'll note that the `groupby` call fails.)

Comment: Then try  this instead: `df_rolling = df.groupby('label').rolling(window='7D', min_periods=1, on='date').sum()`. This should solve your problem (i.e. result in a unique 'label' index level in both versions).
`

Comment: Actually, it think it should be `df_rolling = df.set_index('date').groupby('label').rolling(window="7D", min_periods=1).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it solves your problem as I cannot test it on both versions, but, give a try using `inplace=True` parameter as follow:

```
df_rolling.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Doing this, you don't need to re-assign the whole DF back to the same variable.

One major problem in Python is that the equal sign `=`not only assign the value from the right to the left, but also from the left to the right, hence, if you write

```
a = b
```

It will literally means A gets B value AND B gets A value. So, back to your problem, it might be that compiler throws an exception when you are trying to assign the "reset indexed DF" version of the DF to the original_indexed BF , **AND** the other way around at the same time.

Another option could be using a temporary DF with `.copy()` method , as follow:

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame(blabla...)
tempDF = myDF.reset_index()
myDF = tempDF.copy()
```

I would prefer the "inplace" solution if both of them work. Give them a try and report the outcome.

Comment: I'm afraid `df_rolling.reset_index(inplace=True)` raises an identical exception.  I think the issue may be with the way the index is created/modified, rather than with the reset_index call?  If you notice the two code blocks, the output of `df_rolling.index` is quite different from version to version.

Comment: `names=['label', 'label', 'date'])`  ....two columns with same name ? 'label' ?

Comment: Right, even though the original data only has one column with the title `'label'`, and the call to `set_index` doesn't have `'label'` in its arguments twice!